# Run a cron job only once after a set time

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to run a cron job to perform a specific cloud function after a set interval only once but a bit unsure of how to do it. Is there any way to do this through the current google cloud platform?

Answer (score 3):

Update following our discussion below through comments:

If you want to "change a document in your Firestore database 2 hours after it has been created" you could do as follows:

1. When creating the document in Firestore, save the date/time of creation, e.g. with `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`
2. Have an HTTP Cloud Function that you call regularly as explained below (every minutes? every 5 minutes?) and that, first, selects the documents that were created 2 hours ago (based on the saved timestamp) and then do the desired action on these docs.

---

If you want to trigger a Cloud Function through a cron job, note that you would normally do that through an HTTP Cloud Function, calling the Cloud Function URL via the cron job.

You can either use an external service like [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/) or you can use GCP's App Engine and Cloud Pub/Sub

See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEBPAMSk5_8

and this Blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

both from the Firebase team.

---

Finally note that recently GCP launched a new product, [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/), which can be used to call HTTP Cloud Functions.

Comment: The vids focus on cron tasks that occur regularly at a timer. What I'm asking tho is if there is a way to trigger a task only once sometime after an event happens

Comment: Which kind of "event"? Event in Firestore?

Comment: an onCreate trigger in the firestore. Basically after a document is generated I want to trigger another function that changes a document in the database. I used to do it all through a single function (through async await) but the timeout is only 9 minutes and I need it to perform something after 2 hours

Comment: So I uderstand that you want to trigger a Cloud Function, two hours after an event occured in Firestore. Is that right?

Comment: Well im not sure if its the right way to do it but yes. I want to change a document in the firestore 2 hours after it has been created

Comment: I understand task queues could be a way to do them but I dont fully understand how they work. Like I understand they need a http request to activate but how do I return a http request from an onCreate cloud function? Is that even possible?

Comment: The idea is that with the onCreate Cloud Function you "mark" the documents as "to be called in 2 hours" and you use another Cloud Function to regularly check if there are documents that were marked 2 hours before. I hope it is clear!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still a bit confused, however, So the first function would be an onCreate that would output all of the elements to be edited in 2 hours? How would I output an https request from an onCreate trigger tho? And the second function triggering every 5 minutes would be scheduled as a cron job (every 5 minutes)? Sorry if I sound dumb I am still new to this and it is very confusing.

Comment: If you could give me 5 minutes to chat privately it would help so much I've been struggling on this for about 12 hours

Comment: Never mind. Looks like I don't have enough reputation I can't speak in chat unfortunately, looks like I'm stuck

Comment: Sorry for that. I think I cannot help you more.... Try to understand the concept and don't loose courage while trying and coding!

Comment: Hi, I have tried and think I almost found a solution. Problem is I am struggling the part where I create an array of the new messages with timestamps. I managed to create a timestamp variable for each in the database but when I read it from the http function after it is just an empty array so I don't know how I would store the list of messages from one function to the other...

Comment: I don't know your data model but I would not create an array but save the timestamp in each message document itself. Courage!

Comment: And then to find the ones to change would I have to query the whole database every time tho?

Comment: No you just query for the ones that have a timestamp > 2 hours (you can remove the timestamp when you have treated a doc)

Comment: And to find which ones have it I just subtract the current timestamp with the one on the document? (If I understand correctly)? So the https function would scan the database for any document where (current timestamp - document timestamp < 2 hours) and then update all of those documents..

Comment: Yes that’s it. But you should query for document time stamp < current timestamp - 2 since you cannot make math calculations in the query.

Comment: I managed to create the following query and used the .get() to receive the querySnapshot. Then I used snapshot.docs to see all elements in the array. The function runs but I always get an empty array in the firebase console. What mistake am I making??

Comment: On further research I think it is not possible in the current state of the firestore as I would be needing a collection group query (as I would be querying my whole message database to find messages with the correct timestamp). Any alternative suggestions? or perhaps I didn't understand what you meant

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for late answer. Once upon time, I am stuck with this issue too. You sure can schedule a job executed once at particular time. But, you must use multiple platform as Firebase Cloud Function has time limit to cron task. If you look at [Quotas and limits document for Time Limit of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#time_limits), you can see that Firebase cloud functions have set time limits until they are canceled (540 seconds or 9 minutes). So you can't cron a job executed after more than 9 minute with cloud function. But you can use [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com) server to cron a job without paying. Unfortunately, Heroku apps sleep after 30 minutes if there is no task along the time interval. However, you can keep awake with external server such as [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org). You can get unlimitedly your app awake by applying pinging to your Heroku app every minute less than 30 minutes. You can use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to cron a job executed once for all time by using this code there:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

const job = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```

You can get current time or *timestamp* for Firestore and add time interval to current date to schedule as you desire. Dont forget to use timezone for it. You can use rule to set timezone like that:

```
  const rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
  rule.dayOfWeek = [0, new schedule.Range(0, 6)];  //all days
  rule.hour = req.body.hour;
  rule.minute = req.body.minute;
  rule.second = req.body.second;
  rule.tz = "Europe/Istanbul"; // You can specify a timezone!
```

Here, you can get request from client side by fetching time specification from user. And use schedule job module for one time task like that:

```
const job = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(data) {
    console.log("Job ran @", new Date().toString());
  }.bind(null, dataFuture));
```

Here you can use user data with `.bind()` by entering variable just like `dataFuture` variable. If your users use native android platform, you can specify time interval by entering `hour_of_day` and `minute` as:

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
Locale aLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(aLocale);                                                
calendar.setTime(currentTime);
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);                                                       
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
```

Alternatively you can use [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) platform. But it may be a bit hard to use.